# DOM, javascript, how to use window open

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink

I have to have separate javasvript and html-files and I'm trying to open a new window when I click on a link, but it is not working.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java3.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a href="#" id="link">Click!</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById("link");
a.onclick = function(){
window.open("http://www.google.com");
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the console you will likely see an error message like:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

This is because `document.getElementById("link")` is `null`.

Why is it `null`? It's right there on the page!

Well, not when this code runs. The JavaScript code runs *before* the body is defined.

Either move your script down, or wrap your code in a ready/onload event:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("link");
    a.onclick = function() {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    };
};
```